# Linux perl module management

Tags: perl

Is there any programs other than [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CPAN) to install/compile perl modules and install them?

Mainly I am looking for something like the Activestate PPM, the closest I could find was [PPM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ppm) on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) but when I try to install it fails for some "*unknown*" reason. I am sure if I dug through the output I could find why but it mostly greek to me about make errors.

Anyhow is there anything? It would be nice if it had a GTK front end on account of I use GNOME on Ubuntu and it would be nice for playing with new modules.

What I really want is the ability to install and uninstall modules by command line atleast.

Also, is it possible to script a perl module install? For example when someone installs my .DEB package is there a way for it to retrieve the source code from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) (using [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CPAN) if need be) and build it for the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to install Perl modules.  The [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN) shell, [CPANPLUS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPANPLUS) and the new [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3acpanminus).  You can also download and install the tarballs manually resolving the dependencies manually.

But it seems you want Debian packages, presumably for CPAN modules (or versions of them) which do not already come from Debian.  For that there are several options.  [dh-make-perl](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/78) packages individual modules but does not handle dependencies.  [dh-make-pm](http://search.cpan.org/~jkutej/Debian-Apt-PM-0.04/script/dh-make-pm) uses dh-make-perl to handle all the dependencies.  On an alternative track, there is [CPANPLUS::Dist::Deb](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPANPLUS%3a%3aDist%3a%3aDeb) which uses CPANPLUS to make Debian packages.

Comment: I am not really looking for DEB packages of the modules, I am more looking for a way to distribute the required modules with my project, which will be created into a DEB package. The CPANPLUS::Dist::Deb looks very very interesting.

Comment: I looked at dh-make-perl and found a quick how to for it, absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu (your mentioned OS), use the CLI (Command Line Interface) with Aptitude. It is easy to install Perl modules this way. 99% of the modules you will find on CPAN are available for install this way.

Syntax for searching available modules:

**apt-cache search [keywords]**

Below: Example search for the "Template" module for Perl (include perl in the search keywords to make sure you are looking at perl modules). The search is performed on the description, not the title so this gives you latitude in your search terms.

**apt-cache search template perl**

Install the module you found

**sudo apt-get install libtemplate-perl**

or perhaps you would prefer

**sudo apt-get install libhtml-template-perl**

and you could also grab the docs

**sudo apt-get install libtemplate-perl-docs**

The module name is usually in the format

**lib[module]-perl**

With the module part being the proper CPAN name. However, sometimes this is not exact. the 'apt-cache search' will find what you are looking for. Additionally, because the search is performed on description over title, you will find other "like-minded" modules.

Have fun..

Answer (score 4):

[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) has a more graphical module manager.

Answer (score 0):

The cpan files are held on an FTP server, often you can download them, extract them and run Make yourself, but, at the same time, if its missing dependencies, or requires updates, this will still be the case.

Comment: Any specific reason why people have down graded this ? Afterall, its true!

Comment: "I had soup for lunch" is true, but that doesn't make it a good answer to this question. :P  Telling someone they can download and compile the source is not very helpful.  I'm pretty sure they know that and I know it's a tedious solution.

Comment: Oddly enough, this is the solution I pretty much ended up using. I found a program call dh-make-perl. I downloaded the tarballs of the modules I need and made .deb files out them very easily.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted Solignis